# objective-c syntax question

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm trying to learn objective-c, and have a question regarding this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), the method name is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and it takes 2 parameters, the table view and the index path. It returns a pointer to a `UITableViewCell`.

So, the `(UITableViewCell *)` represents the return type, but what I don't understand is why the tv parameter occurs **before** the cellForRowAtIndexPath method name. It looks to me like what we have here is return type, then param1, then method name, then param2.

I'm really still trying to get an understanding of basic objective-c syntax so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, all of it, not just `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

The `-` at the beginning means it is an instance method, if it were a class method it would be a `+`. Eg when you `alloc` an object,`alloc` is a class method.

The return type is inside the first brackets. If the method doesn't return anything then the brackets will contain `void`.

Then comes the first part of the method name, this is between the closing bracket of the return type an the first colon. If the method has no parameters then there is no colon.

Immediately after the colon is the first parameter's type inside brackets.

Immediately after the brackets comes the name of the first parameter.

After a space the method name continues in the same fashion.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are quite correct in your description. The basic syntax of a method is

```
(ReturnObjectType *)someMethodWithInput1:(Input1Type *)input1 
                               andInput2:(Input2Type *)input2
                                andAnInt:(int)input3;
```

In general, Objective-C doesn't have named parameters, so everything on the left side of a colon is part of the method name. For this example:

```
- (return_type)instanceMethodWithParameter:(param1_type)param1_varName 
                         andOtherParameter:(param2_type)param2_varName;
```

The method name is `instanceMethodWithParameter:andOtherParameter;`. If you use the above to declare the function, e.g. in a header file, then you can change the parameter names in the implementation without a problem. So those are really just for convenience.

Comment: "in general objective-c doesn't have named parameters"? Huh?

Comment: @Jonathan: the parameters of a function don't have names, e.g. `doStuff:(int)a` is the exact same function as `dostuff:(int)b`.

Comment: @PengOne, right I understand what you mean, but the parameters do have names, in your examples `a` and `b`, don't they?

Comment: @Jonathan: It doesn't. The language doesn't have named parameters, or more precisely keyword parameters, as a feature (as, say, Python does with keyword arguments). By convention, the segments of the method name are used to identify the parameter that comes after, but this is just a convention. The parameters are still strictly sequential and have no actual relationship to the selector.

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't believe it's correct to say that methods have "named parameters" because one cannot refer to a parameter of a method by name _outside of the method_. Clearly there is room for a difference of opinion here, and you make a good point. Still, I think the statement is true.

Comment: @Jon The usual meaning of _named parameters_ is the use of names for the parameters _at the call site_. C, for example, doesn’t have named parameters even though you have to give names to parameters when you need to access them _inside the implementation of a function_.

Comment: @PengOne (and @Chuck, and @Bavarious), I'm still learning so it is good to know what the terminology means. Is the names (eg `a` and `b`) just for the programmer. And when the programme runs the parameters are just referred to the first, second, etc parameter? Like when using NSInvocation you set the arguements(/parameters, I assume they mean the same thing?) by index, not key?